# uWSGI "timeout waiting for header" Error

Tags: python, webserver, wsgi, pyramid, uwsgi

I'm using uwsgi-0.9.8.4 under Ubuntu 10.04 (32bit), here's the uwsgi section in my Pyramid application (which works fine with paster) .ini file --

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:6543
master = true
processes = 1
pythonpath = /home/jerry/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/*.egg
pythonpath = /home/jerry/myapp
```

uwsgi runs and binds to port 6543 --

```
$ uwsgi --ini-paste development.ini -b 32768
...
2011-08-23 16:43:11,128 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {}
WSGI application 0 (SCRIPT_NAME=) ready on interpreter 0x9472fa8 pid: 14161 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI master process (pid: 14161)
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (pid: 14170, cores: 1)
timeout waiting for header. skip request.
timeout waiting for header. skip request.
```

But http://localhost:6543/ requests in the browser just time out while uWSGI infrequently reports receiving nothing.

What could be wrong and is there any way to debug this situation?

Any pointer will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uWSGI by default speaks the uwsgi (all lowercase) protocol, not the http one. So you cannot connect to it via browser. Add --protocol=http to let it speak http (slower obviously)

Comment: Thank you very much! With "--protocol *** UNDOCUMENTED OPTION ***" I would never be able to figure it out myself.